# Perfect hashing function algorithm

Tags: algorithms, hash, hash-tables

Is there a good (perfect) hashing algorithm for the following problem?

We have $n \ll m$ (say $n=150$ and $m=5\times 10^{12}$) and we want a hash table  to store integers up to $m$ whose prime factors are all smaller than $n$.

Comment: Does it really need to be a [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)?  What's wrong with using a good hash function (e.g., a 2-universal hash) and using standard methods to deal with collisions?  I wonder if this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).  If it has to be a perfect hash function, are you OK with solutions that first generate all such integers and store them all in memory and then do processing work that is proportional to the number of such integers?  Or do you need a hash function that requires no preprocessing to find?

Comment: @D.W. preprocessing time doesn't really matter, but I want the accessing (constant) times to be low, it doesn't need to be perfect but would be nice if it was